# Proper way to upload multiple images to Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parse-platform

I am saving multiple images by using an open source custom class called ELCImagePicker. The code to use the ELCImagePicker is found within the ViewDidLoad method of the controller for the specific tab.

```
ELCImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[ELCImagePickerController alloc]initImagePicker];
        imagePicker.maximumImagesCount = 20;
        imagePicker.imagePickerDelegate = self;

        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Currently, the method I am using to upload the images itself to Prase which is a backend as a service is

```
- (void)elcImagePickerController:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSArray *)info
{
    NSData *fileData;
    NSString *fileName;
    NSString *fileType;

    for(id image in info){

        fileData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        fileName = @"image.png";

        PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:fileName data:fileData];
        [imageFile saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (error){
                UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Image Upload Error" message:@"please try sending your image again" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [errorAlert show];
            }else{
                PFObject *message = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Message"];
                [message setObject:imageFile forKey:@"imageFile"];
                [message setObject:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId] forKey:@"senderId"];
                [message setObject:[[PFUser currentUser] username] forKey:@"username"];
                [message saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                    if (error){
                        UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Image Upload Error" message:@"please try sending your image again" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                        [errorAlert show];
                    }
                }];


            }
        }];
    }

}
```

First and foremost, info is an array which contains the multiple images that are selected. I am currently enumerating through the array and than using Parse's custom API to upload the images. So far I am getting an error message which reads: "**2014-04-28 11:03:58.574 One Take[42357:90b] -[__NSDictionaryM CGImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe9749b0
2014-04-28 11:03:58.582 One Take[42357:90b]**  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM CGImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe9749b0'
 **First throw call stack:**"

I am wondering what is a proper method in order to upload multiple images to parse, I'm not sure if its a good practice to even do what I am currently doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parse part isn't what's throwing the error, the `id image in info` is wrong.  It returns dictionaries, so you're trying to convert a dictionary to a UIImage.

It should be:

```
for (NSDictionary * dictionary in info) {
    UIImage *image = dictionary[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]; //ELC packages its dictionaries with the same key as UIImagePicker
    fileData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

    // ... the rest of your code ... //

}
```

Your parse saves aren't necessarily a problem; however, they might be problematic because they don't keep track of which photo triggered the error.  Perhaps keep track of the error photos in a separate array, then notify the user which photos failed to upload.  Then give them the option to try again on just those photos.

Comment: I tried it and this works out. Could you explain in a bit more detail about whats happening behind the scenes? Info is an array, but the ELCImagePicker holds images in a dictionary?

Comment: Sure can.  Your original code was enumerating through the array `info` and trying to convert each object inside of `info` into a PNGRepresentation of an image.  The problem is that `info` is really an array of dictionaries.  This means that the image is stored under the key `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage`.  We use this to retrieve the image that was stored in the dictionary.  There is probably other information stored in the dictionary that is relevant to some people. I haven't personally worked with this controller, so I'm not sure what that info is.  Does that help clear things up?

Comment: Sure does, I'm curious as to how you first discovered that those images are stored as dictionaries.

Comment: Well, I looked at your error logs and saw "[__NSDictionaryM CGImage]" which lead me to believe you were converting incorrectly.  Then, I went to the ELC github and found this sentence: "Instead of returning one dictionary representing a single image the controller sends back an array of similarly structured dictionaries."  Then, I found the demo file to see what key the image was stored under.